# How do I linear search two arrays in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, cout, linear-search

I have two arrays of data type double - called array1[10] and array2[8]. I am required to search for array2 inside array1 at each element using a linear search function. The function declaration is

```
string linSearch (double array1[10], double array2[8]);
```

If array2 is found inside array1 then I need to print out the index of where it is found in array1. If its not found I need the output to be "NA". This output must be a delimited-comma- string.
eg.

```
//given the two arrays:
array1={1.1,1.2,6,7,3.5,2,7,8.8,9,23.4}
array2={6,45,2,7,1.1,5,4,8.8}

//after the linear search completes, the output must be the index in which //array2 is found in array1. if its not found, then it must be NA:

2,NA,5,6,0,NA,NA,7
```

So far I have the code that follows. Its my first time working with arrays and I am still having difficulties grasping the concept- like once I define the function how do I even call it in the main program?! anyway..the function definition I have (excluding the main program) is:

```
string linSearch (double array1[10], double array2[8])
{
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 =0;
    int position =-1;
    bool found = false;
    while (index1<10 && !found && index2<8)
    {
        if array1[index1] == array2[index2])
        {
            found = true;
            position = index1;
        }
        index1++;
        index2++;
    }

    return position;

}
```

I am EXTREMELY confused about searching for one array in the other and how to output the delimited list as well as how to connect it to my main program. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: the position is where the second array starts?

Comment: also in your current code you return even if only one number from array2 is in array one

Comment: no, the position is to record the position of the search value and the variable index2 is where the second array starts.

Comment: @N7c Show examples of arrays when one is found in the second.

Comment: please add example input and example output, It is not clear how you get an output of 4 entries (`2,NA,6,7`) from arrays of size 10 and 8

Comment: @N7c What result will be for arrays got example { 1 } and { 1, 1, 1 }?l

Answer (score 1):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string linSearch(double array1[10], double array2[8])
{

    string result = "";
    bool found;
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
    {
        if(j > 0)
            result.append(", ");

        found = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            if (array1[i] == array2[j]) {
                result.append(to_string(i));
                found = true;
            }
        }
        if(!found)
            result.append("NA");
    }
    return result;
}

int main(){

    double a1[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    double a2[8] = {11, 25, 3, 41, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    cout << linSearch(a1, a2) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not searching one array inside the other. You are searching for elements from one array in a second array. If you are using a linear search and if you do not want to sort the array, you need 2 nested loops to do that. One for each element in the second array, and one to find that element in the first array.

Keep things simple and start with finding the position of a single element in one array. Because you are comparing `double`s, you should not compare them with `==`. Next you just need a function that calls the first for each element in the second array:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>    
#include <iostream>


void index_to_string(const std::vector<double>& v,double e,std::ostream& out){
    auto it = std::find_if(v.begin(),
                           v.end(),
                           [e](const double& x) {
                               return std::abs(e-x) < 1e-8;
                           }
                        );
    if (it == v.end()) {
        out << "NA";
    } else {
        out << (it - v.begin());
    }
}

void all_indices_to_string(const std::vector<double>& v1,const std::vector<double>& v2,std::ostream& out){
    if (v1.size() == 0 || v2.size()==0) return;
    index_to_string(v1,v2[0],out);
    for (size_t i=1;i<v2.size();++i){
        out << ",";
        index_to_string(v1,v2[i],out);
    }
}

int main() {
    double array1[] ={1.1,1.2,6,7,3.5,2,7,8.8,9,23.4};    
    double array2[] ={6,45,2,7,1.1,5,4,8.8};
    all_indices_to_string(
        std::vector<double>(std::begin(array1),std::end(array1)),
        std::vector<double>(std::begin(array2),std::end(array2)),
        std::cout
    );
}
```

Output:

```
2,NA,5,3,0,NA,NA,7
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Unfortunately, as the assignment requirement, we are not allowed to use vectors

Comment: @N7c thats a pity. You can take it as an exercise to refactor the code to first replace the vector arguments with begin and end iterators and then it is only a tiny step to pass pointers to the first/last element in the arrays. Btw if there is such a requirement you should mention it in the question, because not using vectors is basically not using c++

Answer (score 1):

In your example of arrays and the expected output

```
//given the two arrays:
array1={1.1,1.2,6,7,3.5,2,7,8.8,9,23.4}
array2={6,45,2,7,1.1,5,4,8.8}
```

and

```
2,NA,5,6,0,NA,NA,7
       ^
```

there is a typo. The output should be

```
2,NA,5,3,0,NA,NA,7
       ^
```

because the number 7 is found in the third position of the array `array1`.

Here you are.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string linearSearch( const double a1[], size_t n1, const double a2[], size_t n2 )
{
    std::ostringstream os;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ )
    {
        if ( i != 0  ) os << ',';

        size_t j = 0;

        while ( j < n1 && a2[i] != a1[j] ) ++j;

        if ( j == n1 ) os << "NA";
        else os << j;
    }

    return os.str();
}


int main() 
{
    double a1[] = { 1.1, 1.2, 6, 7, 3.5, 2, 7, 8.8, 9, 23.4 };
    const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
    double a2[] = { 6, 45, 2, 7, 1.1, 5, 4, 8.8 };
    const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );

    std::cout << linearSearch( a1, N1, a2, N2 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2,NA,5,3,0,NA,NA,7
```